# How can I resolve the error 'str' object has no attribute 'is_paused' in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

> [2023-02-19 05:14:12] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command play
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
> ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\toto\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\music_bot-main\main.py", line 101, in play
> elif self.is_paused:
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_paused'

> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
> await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
> File "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
> await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
> File "C:\Users\toto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
> raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_paused'

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import asyncio

# import all of the cogs
# from help_cog import help_cog
# from music_cog import music_cog

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user} (ID: {client.user.id})')
    print('------')


# remove the default help command so that we can write out own
client.remove_command('help')


# register the class with the bot
# bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
# client.add_cog(music_cog(client))
# code du bot
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        # all the music related stuff
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        # 2d array containing [song, channel]
        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                               'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

    # searching the item on youtube
    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception:
                return False

        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            # get the first url
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            # remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # infinite loop checking
    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            # try to connect to voice channel if you are not already connected
            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                # in case we fail to connect
                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            # remove the first element as you are currently playing it
            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False


@client.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Plays a selected song from youtube")
async def play(ctx, self, *args):
    query = " ".join(args)

    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if voice_channel is None:
        # you need to be connected so that the bot knows where to go
        await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
    elif self.is_paused:
        self.vc.resume()
    else:
        song = self.search_yt(query)
        if type(song) == type(True):
            await ctx.send(
                "Could not download the song. Incorrect format try another keyword. This could be due to playlist or a livestream format.")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
            self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

            if self.is_playing == False:
                await self.play_music(ctx)


@client.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
    if self.is_playing:
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = True
        self.vc.pause()
    elif self.is_paused:
        self.is_paused = False
        self.is_playing = True
        self.vc.resume()


@client.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing with the discord bot")
async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
    if self.is_paused:
        self.is_paused = False
        self.is_playing = True
        self.vc.resume()


@client.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the current song being played")
async def skip(self, ctx):
    if self.vc != None and self.vc:
        self.vc.stop()
        # try to play next in the queue if it exists
        await self.play_music(ctx)


@client.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays the current songs in queue")
async def queue(self, ctx):
    retval = ""
    for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
        # display a max of 5 songs in the current queue
        if (i > 4): break
        retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + "\n"

    if retval != "":
        await ctx.send(retval)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No music in queue")


@client.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the music and clears the queue")
async def clear(self, ctx):
    if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
        self.vc.stop()
    self.music_queue = []
    await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")


@client.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from VC")
async def dc(self, ctx):
    self.is_playing = False
    self.is_paused = False
    await self.vc.disconnect()


@client.command()
async def bonjour(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Bonjour")


# start the bot with our token

client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: Should `async def play(ctx, self, *args):` have `ctx` and `self` switched?

Answer (score 1):

You've given lots of non-class methods the `self` parameter. So `self` ends up being your `context` object and `ctx` the command argument. Just remove `self` from the methods that don't need it. ie, every method that doesn't belong to a class.

```py
async def play(ctx, *args):
    ...


async def pause(ctx, *args):
    ...


async def resume(ctx, *args):
    ...


async def skip(ctx):
    ...


async def queue(ctx):
    ...


async def clear(ctx):
    ...


async def dc(ctx):
    ...
```

Above are the ones that need changing.

Comment: when i try to delete self my commands still doesn't work because i use self.is_paused to check if the bot is currently paused.
Do i need to implement these command in my music class?

Comment: Either you need to be able to reference the music class in other functions and do `music.is_paused`, etc. Or they should be commands in the Music Cog as well so they can access the class properties.